# plot graph of temperature coming from API in angular

Tags: angular, socket.io

I want to display a graph of data coming from node js end through socket.io

**TS:**

```
this.socket = socketIo('http://192.168.0.108:8000');
this.socket.on('img', (obj) => {
    this.temp=JSON.parse(obj)
    this.temperature=this.temp.temperature;

    let data = [
        {
            x: [this.time],
            y: [this.temperature]
        }
    ];

    plot(newLocal, data);

    let update = {
        x: [[this.time]],
        y: [[this.temperature]]
    };
    //this.temperature has temperature value

    var cnt = 0;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
        extendTraces(newLocal, update, [0])
        cnt = cnt+1;
        if(cnt === 100) clearInterval(interval);
    }, 500);
})
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="card">
    <div id="graph"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: How do you plan to make a graph? Have you used any library to draw?

Comment: yes i have used plotly.js to draw graph